# Tkinter: Use different font (color, size, etc.) for the text within the same button?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have a very specific question.

I have a tkinter button. Each time I click it I get a pop-up window with an Entry box. Enter a text and press enter I can change the text of this button. I can do it as many time as the as I want.

Now the question is:
can I make the button text to have different color and font size?
Say the original button text is "btn 1". The first time I click it. The text becomes "btn 1\nFirstClick". The second time the text is ""btn 1\nFirstClick\nSecondClick".

I have all the code worked out as I wanted. But now I want "FirstClick" to be in Red and "SecondClick" to be in Green".

Is that possible? I googled and can't find the answer.

Comment: The ONLY stylistic variation possible in a single Button is that you can underline a single character, that's it.  If you must do this, you'd need to use a read-only Text; with the right border, relief, and background options, and mouse event bindings, you can make it look and act rather button-like.  (It's not going to match native buttons on all platforms, of course.)

Comment: @martineau, those apply to the entire text of the Button - OP wants separate styling per line of text.

Comment: @jasonharper:OK, sorry, you're right. I'll delete my earlier comments.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiple fonts or colors in a single button. Your only option would be to create a custom widget that looks and behaves like a button, but which is implemented with a `Text` or `Canvas` widget. Those two widgets allow you to use multiple colors and fonts at the same time.